# I keep getting "Event not found" when I want to open calendar by EventId

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

this is my code for adding an event to my calendar(MyFragment):

```
    int id = 20002000;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events._ID, id);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,"xxxx@hotmail.com");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, myTitle);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {

        date = sdf.parse(stringtodate);

        calDate.setTime(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (date.before(new Date())) {
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,new Date().getTime());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, new Date().getTime());

    }else{
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
    }
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

    startActivity(intent);
```

this is my method for retrieving an event by the given id(MainActivity)

```
     Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, 20002000);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you add stacktrace?

Comment: I have same problem. Classic Google - their APIs, especially calendar, are so buggy it almost hurts to use them. Just from top of my head - EDIT intent doesnt work as it should, it only opens event for VIEW and not for EDIT (this bug was reported 8 years ago and its still unsolved and they didnt even update documentation to mention it), or for example this occasional "Even not found" bug, or sometimes whewn you try to open some event, it shows bad date (1.1.1970).